# Have edited an answer of someone, and got the following reaction

Tags: support

At this answer [Access violation for object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27429507/4042114) I made an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6878912). It is reject by 2/3.

The reason given is that I was trying to address the answerer and it had to be a comment.

It made me smile though since I wanted to comment but I am not allowed yet. Adding the edit as an answer is really out of the question in any case. Can't this be taking into consideration when the edit is completly in line and actually essential for a bug-free application?

Just to be specific, I would gain 2 rep so I am shortly allowed to comment.

[what I edited is in bold]

> 3)
>
> This code will generate string that you need **in a normal fashion**:
>
> ```
> std::ostringstream newStringStream;
> newStringStream << "Sphere_" << i;
> std::string newString = newStringStream.str();
> ```
>
> **To keep the multi-byte consistancy in your application the last line should be:**
>
> ```
> **Ogre::String newString = newStringStream.str();**
> ```

Comment: This falls into the hard to justify area of "editing code in anything". Where the answer usually is, "Don't do that". At least its an answer, you should **never** edit code in a question.

Comment: Changing code in a question would rip out the heart of the question indeed.

Comment: In this aspect, StackExchange is flawed, but it is to avoid spam. What you can try it to answer the question and explain why you can't comment it. Suddenly, you might be able to comment on the question itself. You can delete the answer after, re-opening if needed.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Don't advocate posting non-answers as answers. It just makes more work.

Comment: @Deduplicator How else will he do the right thing and comment?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: By following the conventions. Answering whitout it being an answer can't be right.

Comment: @Ruijter What are the conventions? Do not comment? Try to get reputation by all means so he can comment a question?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: The fact is, that wouldn't be what he would do there. And he just needs 29 more rep, which is less than any of 3 answer-upvotes, 2 accepts, 15 worthwhile edit-suggestions, or a combination thereof. That's really not hard.

Comment: @Deduplicator It isn't hard for someone who already knows how the website works.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: So, you propose asking to be stepped on *hard* by irritating those already there as a way to get there faster? BTW, it's not so long ago I had 0 rep.

Comment: @Deduplicator: HA, I never had 0 rep :P All: patience is to go, while I am addressing this point, a quick way to step one metre doesn't exist and shouldn't (have) been invented.

Comment: @Deduplicator I read what you said over and over again and I still don't get what you meant

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Was just a bit flippantly saying that I'm not here long enough yet not to remember how to get started. Before that, I said Rujiter isn't so far from getting the privilige to comment everywhere, and (knowingly) doing the wrong thing would backlash, which is why advocating doing the wrong thing is extremely counter-productive.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: The same as everyone else: by earning the privilege of posting comments. Posting comments as answers typically makes it harder to get that privilege, as you get downvotes and lose any rep you've earned. Editing existing answers to bypass not having earned the privilege is not acceptable either. Don't advocate bad conduct to bypass the need to earn privileges in order to exercise them.

Comment: @Deduplicator I agree with you. But honestly, what else can be done? He obviously wanted to help and did what he knew. Sometimes we have to do something wrong to do the right thing. In this case, the wrong thing is kind-of justifiable.

Comment: @KenWhite The idea is to pass the information. Also, if the question is put as `Community Wiki` and deleted, there won't be any penalisations in his reputation.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: That doesn't matter. The poster should *follow the site guidelines, just like everyone else*, and your advice to ignore them is absolutely wrong, no matter how you try to justify it. Privileges at [se] are **earned**, and everyone has to meet the same requirements to earn them. If that's not acceptable to you, go somewhere else.

Comment: @KenWhite Rudeness isn't acceptable either, yet you just made use of it

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: I was not rude. It was a clear statement of fact: If you don't like the guidelines here and don't want to follow them, find another site where the guidelines don't exist. By using this site, you agree to abide by the rules here; if you're not going to do so, you should not be here. There's nothing rude, no personal attack, or anything else. It's a clear statement addressed to any one who reads it; the use of *you* did not mean you individually or personally.

Comment: @KenWhite Can you suggest a way to pass the information without it being lost because of lack of reputation?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Yes. Earn the minimal amount of reputation required to be able to post a comment. There is an entire post here somewhere about how new users can get started on [so], and many, many ways to earn the few reputation points required. The information can be passed at that point. The problem with making changes to a posted answer to do so is that if the added information is wrong or stated badly, it can negatively affect the reputation of the answer's author, who had nothing to do with the edit. You would not like it if I changed your answer and cost you downvotes as a result.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't like when people edit my questions without leaving a comment. If I see the edit was actually needed, i keep it and swallow my pride. Otherwise, I roll it back. But in this case, the edit would hurt a lot the question. And the suggestion is to comment, but he doesn't have reputation to do so. Honestly, I find it hard to get reputation. So, I have to find a way to pass the information so it isn't lost. Waiting 2-3 days to comment on a question isn't exactly a "solution". There are 3 options: 1) leave it, 2) do as I said to do or 3) try to somehow make a chat.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Unless the question is in an extremely niche tag, it's highly doubtful that this poster is the only one aware of the additional information. Another user with sufficient rep can comment to provide it if it's that critical that it can't wait a day or two. Invalid/inappropriate edits are not the solution here. Is the missing information risking a major system meltdown, security breach, or risk someone's physical well-being? If not, it's not important enough to warrant not following the guidelines established here *by the users of these sites*, and you have no right to do so.

Comment: Am a bit confused. If you need to earn rep to comment on a question/answer and you should follow the rules, how come I am able to edit all posts - of which here is stated *the wrong*. The edit (added) is peer reviewed. Besides my edit wasn't wrong, it is a real improvement since the library's authors advices to use Ogre::String rather then any other. Noticing the answerer only once participated in the tag `Ogre`, namely the mentioned question, she propably didn't knew this. So, how come it was, regarding the comments above, the wrong thing to do?

Comment: @Ruijter But it isn't answering to the question itself: you are changing it. If someone answers to the question, you may answer it to complete that answer with that information. I see this being done a lot!